# Проблема с расчетом расстояния на карте google

Tags: google-maps-api

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать расчет на карте не по дорогам, а просто по прямой линии, так как по дорогам не считает стоимость по всей карте, то есть считает только те, куда есть маршрут на автомобиле. Сам расчет уже сделан, нужно только переделать на прямую линию, самолетом, например. Вот ссылка на сервис http://abtt.ru/test/test1/raschet_stoimosti1.php
      Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: @Shanty4145, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, вас интересует подсчет расстояния между двумя координатами?

Вот тут пример функции на PHP:

http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php

Исходя из принципа, используемого там, можно уже переписать на другой необходимый язык.

**Обновление**

Опять же, если правильно понял, вас интересует, как нарисовать простую линию между двумя координатами. В этой статье есть пример http://habrahabr.ru/post/197448/

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
   path: [new google.maps.LatLng(16.003575733881323, 101.689453125), new google.maps.LatLng(59.934288, 30.3350336)], //указываем точки старта и финиша
   geodesic: true, //устанавливаем флаг геодезической кривой. Так и выглядит лучше и точнее передает кратчайший путь между двумя точками
   map: map //устанавливаем на карту
});
```

Comment: Подсчет стоимости уже имеется, расстояние не требуется, сейчас идет маршрут по дорогам, но, к сожалению, например, из России в Америку нет маршрута на авто, вот, собственно, и не считает, и не прокладывает маршрут, а если сделать, например, просто линией, как здесь http://www.mtrgroup.ru/, то будет расчет по всей карте, но никак пока не пойму, как это сделать в силу того, что не совсем понимаю.